# merge String(char to String)

Tags: java

I am practicing java programing
this is my code,I want to merge 2 string and sort then,

```
public class MergeString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "adfs";
        String str2 = "jiewk";
        String med =mergeString(str1, str2);
        System.out.println(med);
        System.out.println(med.charAt(2));
    }

public static String mergeString(String str1,String str2){
    String merged = str1 +str2;
    char[]merge = merged.toCharArray();
    for (int i =0;i<merge.length;i++){
        for (int j=i+1;j<merge.length-1;j++){
            if (merge[i]>merge[j]){
                char temp = merge[i];
                merge[i]=merge[j];
                merge[j]=temp;

            }
        }
    }
    merged = merge.toString();
    return merged;
}
```

}

could you tell me why my output is ASCII like: [C@6b71769e
thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not ASCII, this seems to be memory address!

Comment: that's the kind of output you get when you print out an instance of a class that doesn't override the toString method.

Comment: just use `return String.valueOf(merge);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `return String.valueOf(merge)`

Comment: I got it ! Thank you very much!